# convert ExceptionDescribe to string

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface

I need to get the output of ExceptionDescribe() in JNI as string so I can write it afterwards in a file instead of writing it directly on command line. Is there any way or idea how to do that?

Thanks in Advance,

Sami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have apparently use the `ExceptionOccured()` method.

```
jthrowable exc;
exc = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question, or why the OP marked it as correct.

Answer (score 8):

ExceptionOccurred is a first step, to get to the message and stack trace one can do:

```
    jboolean isCopy = false;
    jmethodID toString = env->GetMethodID(env->FindClass("java/lang/Object"), "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring s = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(exc, toString);
    const char* utf = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(s, &isCopy);
```

Comment: After using utf, you need to explicitly call ReleaseStringUTFChars() to tell JVM that the native code does not need it anymore.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj - well done pointing potential memory leak out. :)

Comment: FYI you can't call FindClass() if an exception is thrown. You have to clear the exception first, but after that I don't even know if you can get the jthrowable object. Seems like a catch 22 situation.

Comment: This gets the exception class name and its message, but not the stack trace.