# How can I redirect the exception stacktrace to log file using JNI in c++?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to call java methods from c++ codes. JNI provides a API called `ExceptionDescribe()` which basically prints the stacktrace on `stderr`. Example code snippet:-

```
JNIEnv** ppObjJNIEnv;
.....
.....
// some java method call using CallObjectMethod() or CallVoidMethod API
if (JNI_TRUE == (*ppObjJNIEnv)->ExceptionCheck()) {
    (*ppObjJNIEnv)->ExceptionDescribe();
    return -1;
}
```

But I want to log the exception in some log file or (say) syslog.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015293/convert-exceptiondescribe-to-string

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but I think you need to use either JNI or Java to redirect System.stderr to another stream ( i.e. a log file in your case ).

In theory you should be able to do that from JNI in a manner like this :

- save the reference to the current System.stderr
- Create a new stream ( you might need to cache that, and use a global reference to avoid GC if you do cache it ).  If it's cached and already open then just use that, of course.
- Set System.stderr to that new stream, it's just a static field in System.
- Make your calls to get the Exception details
- Restore System.err to it's saved value
- Flush and (optionally) close your stream ( if you're not keeping it open ).

As I say, haven't tried that myself, but it's what I'd try myself if I wanted to do that.